# Looking for a list of Star Wars minifigures

Tags: minifigures, star-wars

I just started a collection of minifigures of LEGO but exclusively of Star Wars (Although also I include some monster, like the dewack), so my question is simple.

How or where can I get a list of minifigures that currently exist?

Is it something that can be obtained or are simply guided by other things to have these collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com) is your friend. Use the Catalog Search function to find all Star Wars related minifigures ever produced (all 896 of them as per today). Clicking on each minifig gives you the set(s) it came in.

Here are the results if you search for Type = Minifig, Theme = Star Wars, ordered by year of release: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=5&pg=1&catLike=W&catType=M&catID=65

Comment: oh yes, is perfect. One question more about the BrickLink page is a good site for buy ?

Comment: BrickLink is THE marketplace for LEGO (especially for things you cannot buy from shop.lego.com). Just remember that prices do not include shipping, and if you are unsure of how much it would cost to ship something, you need to read the store terms and/or request a quote from the seller before placing an order.

Answer (score 1):

The most complete list there is - [www.minifigs.nl](http://www.minifigs.nl/) - His database is jaw-dropping and always up-to-date.